# What is the exact meaning of this Apple Diagnostics code?

Tags: battery

I've got the dreaded all-cores-at-100% and all-fans running problem on my MacBook Pro 2012 15". iStats reports the battery is at -128C (and it seems ridiculous in a very Apple way to run the fans AND peak the cores because of this). I ran Apple Diagnostics and the error code is:

4BAT/6/40000005: 0x8b7df190

Ok, so it's a battery issue. But what exactly is the issue? I just recently installed an SSD but all the cables and connectors are as they should be. ??

Comment: First rule of troubleshooting: undo any changes you recently made *even if it seems to be unrelated.*

Comment: If I do that the machine will not boot. The change was the  replacement of a mechanical drive with an SSD, which has nothing to do with temperature sensing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error produced by the battery, but exactly what it means is known only to Apple techs.

You should at least check your battery stats using System Information in the Utilities folder. Click on the Power item in the list. Results are displayed on the right.
Be sure to test with the charger disconnected as well as connected.

Check also all contacts and assure that the battery is charging.
If you use a third-party battery, it might be bad, or even if from Apple.

My personal suspicion is that when you replaced the disk you have undone
some contact or caused some other damage, perhaps by working with ungrounded hands.

If you cannot find a bad contact or some other issue,
I would really suggest, if available at your location,
to consider making an appointment at the Apple Genius Bar for service.
It would be impossible for us to foresee what was done inside your computer
while replacing the disk.

Comment: I installed TG Pro and it turns out all the sensors are working properly, including those of the battery, and temps are all normal. This is VERY weird.